# Is there a way to make file upload inputs match a dijit theme in Zend Framework?

Tags: css, zend-framework, zend-form, dojo

I've been looking at the Zend_Dojo_Form_Element package and can't seem to find a file upload input, so I'm stuck with a plain file upload with no theme style next to the rest of my nicely themed elements such as SubmitButton and ComboBox.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there an elegant solution to apply the dijit theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've already looked at this : http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

What you could try is creating your own widget that sets this up for you.  You'll need to use a dximage filter for IE support though, YMMV.  Also may not work depending on how you're doing your layout due to element stacking and the need for a relatively positioned parent.